# How to generate code from a CodeStatementCollection?

Tags: c#, codedom

A class I am reusing is populating a CodeStatementCollection which is used in serialization.

I would like to turn this CodeStatementCollection into human readable code.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn a single `CodeStatement` into C# code by using [`GenerateCodeFromStatement()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.generatecodefromstatement) from [`CSharpCodeProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider). To generate C# code from `CodeStatementCollection`, you just need to call it in a loop:

```
static string GenerateCode(CodeStatementCollection statements)
{
    var writer = new StringWriter();

    var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();

    foreach (CodeStatement statement in statements)
    {
        compiler.GenerateCodeFromStatement(statement, writer, null);
    }

    return writer.ToString();
}
```